# "Stretching/Shrinking" data to align it with other data with Excel preferably

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, statistics, finance

Ok, so my question is simple but requires some background. I'm working on a paper regarding the effects on stock price from the index announcement to the effective day.

- The time period varies each time from example 2 to 10 days but usually around 5.
- I'm wanting to make my graph where the point -4 is the first trading day where the announcement is affecting the prices, and 1 is the effective day.

This is something I'm trying to recreate - Price response to additions and deletions:

[image]

- I need to align multiple stock returns so that the announcement date is always on the same point -5 on the graph, and the effective date is always on the 0 position.
- If the difference between the two points is not 5, I'd need to shrink or stretch the data to make it fit into 5 data points.

This is an example of the data I might have - Here I have only 4 trading days of data but I'd need to stretch it for 5 data points to make it align with the -5 and 0 on the chart:

[image]

I tried some methods to create another data point for example using fractions of each point to create another, but that warps the results so it isn't optimal. Also I tried XY Scatter chart on Excel which makes it easy to stretch the data points, but how would I go about averaging a lot of such graphs to one?

Here's some of my attempts, the fraction method consists of making the first point 4/5th of the 1st data point, second point having 1/5th of 1st data point and 3/5th of 2nd data point etc. It keeps the shape of the graph, but it warps the numbers.

The XY Scatter chart method has 2 different graphs but I'd need to average a lot of graphs into one to get the average. Is this possible?

[image]

Just wondering if anyone has good ideas for this? I have a larger data set so this is going to take some time to do.

This is quote from the paper I'm trying to recreate "As we are interested in the price effects around both the announcement day and the effective day, we want to align both days for all event stocks. While the most common difference between the announcement and effective days is five trading days, this
difference may vary from zero to more than a month. We linearly “stretch” the returns to cover five days in event time. If the difference is greater than five days, we shrink the interval to five days. This allows us to align the CAR at the close of trading following the announcement day and the CAR at the close of trading on effective day for all stocks in the sample.", here CAR means the returns. [So here's an illustration what this whole big block of text means. All data points between -5 and 0 need to be condensed or stretched into 5 points for it to be comparable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th5TA.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following formula in column `D` will stretch the days so the empty range in column `C` is adjusted to 5 days:

```
=IF(C2="",D7+5/(MINIFS(C:C,C:C,">0")-MAXIFS(C:C,C:C,"<0")-2),C2*5/(MINIFS(C:C,C:C,">0")-MAXIFS(C:C,C:C,"<0")-2))
```

[image]
Notes:

1. This only works if you have data preceding the blank range (at least one row)
2. You will need a recent version of Excel (2016 or later) to have access to `MAXIFS`

Comment: Using this method with "XY Scatter, how to average?" graph where I managed to get the -5 and 0 points lined up with both graphs, this works for the graph but I'm actually looking to combine around 100 of these graphs into one to get the average and don't know how I would go about doing that. I appreciate the effort.